# Создание сайта с разграничением прав доступа

Tags: php, mysql, логирование, регистрация

Всем привет!
Подскажите, как можно реализовать следующую идею.
На данный момент в отделе компании работа реализована следующим образом: есть сложная Excel таблица, информацию которой наполняют 9 сотрудников. Каждый из них заполняет свою часть в таблице каждый день, т.е. в Excel на каждый день создается новый лист и меняются данные. Есть идея, используя PHP и MySQL, создать сайт. Админ может просматривать все записи в таблице, а каждый из сотрудников отдела может просматривать и редактировать только свою часть таблицы. При этом возможно просматривать записи за прошедшие дни, их также при возможности редактировать, просматривать и удалять. Систему логирования я кое-как написал, но как ее привязать к конкретным данным для конкретного пользователя не имею как понятия, так и знаний.

Comment: Эм, https://www.php.net/docs.php, https://dev.mysql.com/doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете за основу взять **[RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)** - *Role Base Access Control* (Предоставление доступа на основе ролей: `admin`, `user`, `moder`, `guest` - к примеру).

`admin`:

- `read\write\delete` **все** таблицы

`user`:

- `read\write` **только** таблицу `foo`
- `read` **только** таблицу `bar`

---

Вообще вариантов реализовать то, что вы хотите много, к прмиеру есть и другие реализации:

- **[ABAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-based_access_control)** - *Attribut Based Access Control*: Если `manager` открывает таблицу, то предоставить ему `read\write` возможности, если `admin`, то предоставить `read\write\delete` и т.д.
- **[ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list)** - *Access-control List*: Предоставить "Фуужаснову Барону Базовичу" `read\weite` на таблицу с посетителями и `read` на таблицу с сотрудниками.
- **[DAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control)** - *Discretionary access control*: Объедиение в группы - сотрудники из кабинета `foo` могут `read\write` таблицу с посетителями, а сотрудники из кабинета `bar` могут `read\write\delete` таблицу с посетителями.

Comment: Я хотел, чтобы мне помогли в php и mysql, в плане: когда пользователь логинится, то только его часть таблицы отображается для правки. А у меня, админа, отображается полностью таблица всех данных всех пользователей.

Comment: Разве мой ответ не об этом говорит?)